# JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog variable usage

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I am very new to this and I am trying to get the variables to add up during the process of the code in order to print the total at the end, in doing so, I need it to read the selection from the JOptionPane that the user entered and add the value to the total at the end. The code is almost complete but is missing the calculation of the variables.

Q: How do I get the value of any variable based on what the user selects from the JOptionPane and add it to the cumulative total to println at the end?

An ex is as follows:
(Sorry if it isn't formatted correctly, I am working on learning how it should look)

```
 int addons = 0;
       do{
        addons = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would the customer like to add Salad, Smoothie, Sundae or Cone?");
        if (addons == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
            else if (addons == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
              String[] choices2 = { "Salad $"+salad, "Smoothie$"+smoothie, "Sundae $"+sundae, "Cone $"+cone};
                  String extras = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Which addon?",
         "Extras", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, // Use
               choices2, // Array of choices
                    choices2[0]); // Initial choice
                           count++;//Add item to count
                                System.out.println(extras);
               }  //close YES_OPTION parameters               
                   } //close do parameters
        while(addons == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION); // Exit do while loop6
```

Comment: *"I would appreciate any help what so ever!"*  Tips: 1) Plan your time better. 2) When posting to a Q&A site, ask a question. *"Thank you!"*  You're welcome.

Comment: Judging by the title of this question, you have a problem with how to use a `JOptionPane`. Please remove this dump of your code, and illustrate your problem with an example of about 10 lines (an [sscce](http://sscce.org/))

Comment: Andrew, great points. My question is how do I add the variables from the JOptionPane selection to input as a total in the end? Again, completely new at this, I am 8 weeks in. My apologies for any misconceptions.

Comment: Robin, thank you for the feedback will re-post shortly!

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @Robin (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.  2) That seen above at this moment is **not** an SSCCE!  An SSCCE is not 'uncompilable code snippets' but a self contained example.  (As is explained at the link you don't seem to have followed.)